# How do I create a delete command in Disnake?

Tags: discord, bots, disnake

I would like to create a delete command using Disnake.
I want to turn delete the 100 messages on the channel where they were executed.
I would love to know the code!

I would like to make those, but I can't find them in my research.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do smth like in your async message delete function:

`await inter.message.channel.purge(limit=100)`